How to produce same versions with Jenkins and local builds
I intend to use semver2.0 with + added as metadata for main branch.
eg: on main 1.2.3+20241202121212
eg: on release 1.2.3
I will provide major,mino,patch as a parameter to Jenkins.
My problem is, how to build localy from visual studio 2022 and have same results? Snce I do not have Jenkins locally?

When you provide major, minor, and patch as parameters to the Jenkins build, where are the values coming from? Are they stored someplace where they can be fetched and passed to the local build as well?

I gather that I will just manually pass version info to Jenkins when I invoke the build. for regurar builds from Main branch, Jenkins will automatically use last build number and append current date for example. My idea was to get rid of any file in git that stores version information. This way when I make a new release I do not have to make any dummy commits only for verion change.

With SemVer the major, minor, and patch numbers all have meaning and multiple builds should be supported for preparing a new patch. One way to think of the problem then, is that the major, minor, and patch numbers should be in version control and represent the goal that a development branch is working toward. The major.minor.patch does not identify a build. Use the metadata to uniquely identify a build. The metadata could be a time stamp and a name for the agent or host that produced the build.

When I need to support fixes for previous releases, I find it hard to keep version information in git, because the current version could be way ahead of the fix. The only way we figured it should work is only if we have dedicated branches for each major release.

Do you use git tags? Create a tag for a release. The tag marks a specific point in the repo's history. If/when a fix is needed, create a branch based on the tag. With a tag you don't need to create a branch until a branch is needed. A branch based on the release tag will have the version information as of the release.

You can use our software Reliza Hub to synchronize versioning. For this use-case a free SaaS plan would suffice.
See here for details - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/02/27/automatic-version-increments-with-reliza-hub-2-strategies/
For Jenkins specifically you can use our plugin here - https://plugins.jenkins.io/reliza-integration/

Thanks for the answer, but I am looking on a way to do it simpler, without a saas involved. At maximum a Jenkins plugin.
